# Filtering a MobileConnect List via a custom attribute

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

We've got some custom fields set up for our Mobile Connect Lists - one is called _Custom. If I wanted to send a campaign to people with only a particular value in this field (we use it to put a campaign number in)?

In MobileConnect, when I click 'Create List -> Using a Filter' and writing a filter criteria using my '_Custom' field, I get zero results.

Answer (score 0):

Check your MobileConnect Demographics table, this attribute needs to exist there and some Contact records need to have values in it for the filtering to work.

If this `_Custom` exists in AllSubscribers table or some Data Extension in Email Studio, then it wouldn't be found in MobileConnect until it's properly imported to your MobileConnect Demographics table with all the values.

Comment: It is in MobileConnect Demographics and I got no import errors suggesting it didn't read this field from the uploaded .CSV - is there any way to see a MobileConnect list and see all of the fields? The main view only shows a few fields like Contact Key, Locale etc.

Comment: First you need to create this attribute to your MobileConnect Demographics table. You probably got the error because this didn't exist at the time of importing. 

As for your question, yes - go to Contact Builder, Data Designer and open up MobileConnect Data. That's where you create you can map attribute sets or create custom attributes (to which you later import data in)

Comment: it was already created in the MobileConnect Demographics table and I could see it in there in Data Designer. Is there any way I can view my full list with all attributes?